# Break jQuery function execution on failure inside .each() loop

Tags: jquery, function, return, each

I have the following form

```
<input class="required" id="name" value="some content"/>
<input class="required" id="address" value=""/>
<input class="required" id="lastname" value="some content"/>
```

and the following jQuery function. It contains a `.each()` loop to check some inputs. When the check fails, the function should break and return `false`.

```
function check() {
  $('.required').each(function() {
    var input = $(this);
    console.log(input.attr('id'));

    if (input.val() == null || input.val() == '') {
      console.log('*** Failed ***');
      return false;
    }
  });

  console.log('Other code');
  return true;
}
```

Unfortunately, when I run the code I see the following output:

```
name
address
*** Failed ***
Other code
```

The `.each()` loop correctly stops after the first failure, but the check function seems to keep running. How can I break its execution? Here's a [**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/L004kyru/3/).

Comment: You return `false` from each anonymous function, not from `check()`

Answer (score 2):

```
function check() {
  var valid = true;
  $('.required').each(function() {
    var input = $(this);
    console.log(input.attr('id'));

    if (input.val() == null || input.val() == '') {
      console.log('*** Failed ***');
      valid = false;
      return false;
    }
  });

  if (!valid) return false;

  console.log('Other code');
  return true;
}
```

Comment: I give you credit but you should at least explain why it would work (even it is quite comprehensive code)

Answer (score 0):

The `return false` only breaks the `$.each` statement, but the function go on with the next instruction (`console.log('Other code');`).

Answer (score 0):

I've found an alternative solution. The idea is to get the `.required` inputs and then make a classic `for` loop. This avoids the `each()` loop and the anonymous function.

```
function check() {
  var required = $('.required');
  var size = required.size();

  for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    var input = $(required[i]);
    console.log(input.attr('id'));

    if (input.val() == null || input.val() == '') {
      console.log('*** Failed ***');
      return false;
    }
  }

  console.log('Other code');
  return true;
}
```